# How to add data to AnnotationHub

Tags: bioconductor, sequence-annotation, public-databases

I recently started using the Bioconductor AnnotationHub package for accessing lots of common datasets, but I've noticed that there are a lot of newer databases that have not made it into AnnotationHub's collection.

Has anyone had any luck getting databases added to AnnotationHub or adding them manually yourself (I guess via the package process?)?  Is it painful or relatively straightforward?

I love the annotationhub interface, but I'm wondering if it is way too inefficient to add new resources rather than just manually downloading and curating myself.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the description of the package says:

> The AnnotationHub web resource provides a central location where
>   genomic files (e.g., VCF, bed, wig) and other resources from standard
>   locations (e.g., UCSC, Ensembl) can be discovered.

If the new resources aren't in the standard locations it won't be listed by AnnotationHub. The easy/common way to have the data accessible through AnnotationHub is make it available through these standard locations (before publications if you want to give early access).

Another method would be to follow this steps of [the vignette](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/AnnotationHub/inst/doc/CreateAnAnnotationPackage.html#new-resources) to add new resources, but it might involve creating a new package.

Comment: Yeah, the weird thing is that the data I'm speaking of is the BLUEPRINT epigenetic datasets from hematopoietic cells, and this data is already in Ensembl, so I thought it would be accessible by AnnotationHub, but it is not yet.  Looks like I'll just have to do it manually until they update it on AnnotationHub. Thanks for your insight!

Comment: @Reilstein If the addition is recent maybe it hasn't been made it yet to the Hub (I don't really know how does it work internally). You could also contact the maintainers to know more about this issue, perhaps is there an issue they aren't aware of.